# Cross-reference entire enumerate list

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I would like to refer to all the items of an `enumerate` environment, by applying a label to the list. I tried this

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage{amsmath, hyperref, enumerate}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{enumerate}\label{listref}
\item Mary
\item Had
\item A little
\item Lamb
\end{enumerate}
The poem \eqref{listref} is one of the best known childrens' rhymes.
\end{document}
```

but that did not produce the result required. I think labelling the first and the last items on the list is an option, but I was wondering if there is a smoother way of doing this.

Comment: What results should `\eqref{listref}` produce? "Poem (1)" because the referred `enumerate` environment is the first one in your document, or something else?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think this through. I would like for there to be some way of identifying an entire numbered list and to be able to cross-reference using this identification elsewhere in the document. I wonder if this is possible, or if I will have to put this in a float or something like that.

Comment: @lockstep The `\eqref{listref}` actually produces nothing, or, (Doc-start) depending on whether I use the `hyperref` package or not..

Comment: Bear in mind that a list doesn't display its "number" in-text by default even if one adds a (referable) counter to lists. Consider to put your list inside a `figure` environment and to provide a name for this figure with `\caption` -- this way, you may refer to the figure.

Comment: Yes, that is what I realised - there is no in-text way of identifying a list. But I really didn't want to have to set the list out from the rest of the text. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The following may be a possible duplicate: [Label a complete enumeration](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32251/label-a-complete-enumeration). Please take a look as the answers there might help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For numbered environments which can be referenced, LaTeX provides theorem environments. They are not just theorems or definitions, you can use them more generally. You can

- use titles,
- attach the counter to a sectioning,
- share counters,
- and don't have to take care of defining an environment and managing a counter.

Further there are several packages for customizing these numbered environments, such as [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), [`ntheorem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem) and [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools). They provide predefined styles and ways for defining your own style.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{poem}{Poem}
\begin{document}
\begin{poem}\mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip]
  \begin{enumerate}\label{listref}
    \item Mary
    \item Had
    \item A little
    \item Lamb
    \end{enumerate}
\end{poem}
\noindent The poem \eqref{listref} is one of the best known childrens' rhymes.
\end{document}
```

[image: numbered enumerate environment]

For choosing a theorem package for customizing the format, have a look at: [Theorem packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5599/theorem-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict)

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like this:

```
\newcounter{poemcnt}

\newenvironment{poem}%
  {\refstepcounter{poemcnt}\par Poem~\arabic{poemcnt}\begin{verse}}%
  {\end{verse}}

\begin{poem}
  \label{poemref}
  Mary\\
  Had\\
  A Little\\
  Lamb
\end{poem}

The poem~\ref{poemref} is one of the best known childrens' rhymes.
```

P.S.  Mico asked for optional title.  This is a little more involved :)

```
\newcounter{poemcnt}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{poem}[1][]%
  {\refstepcounter{poemcnt}\par Poem~\arabic{poemcnt}%
    \def\@tempa{#1}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else\space(#1)\fi
    \begin{verse}}%
  {\end{verse}}
\makeatother

\begin{poem}[Mary's Little Lamb]
  \label{poemref}
  Mary\\
  Had\\
  A Little\\
  Lamb
\end{poem}
```

Comment: Not trying to dwell too much on the fine points of typesetting poetry, but ... your `poem` environment does not seem to allow for a title. You could fix this by giving the environment an argument, which would be typeset right after `Poem \arabic{poemcnt}`. :-)

Comment: Surely:     \newcounter{poemcnt}

    \makeatletter
    \newenvironment{poem}[1][]%
      {\refstepcounter{poemcnt}\par Poem~\arabic{poemcnt}
        \def\@tempa{#1}\ifx\@tempa\@empty\else\space(#1)\fi
        \begin{verse}}%
      {\end{verse}}
    \makeatother

    \begin{poem}[Mary's Little Lamb]
      \label{poemref}
      Mary\      Had\      A Little\      Lamb
    \end{poem}

Answer (score 3):

In order to cross-reference the poem as a whole, you need to place it in an environment that is itself numbered (more specifically, an environment or grouping that comes with a counter of some sort). For instance, one can cross-reference items in an enumerated list by attaching labels to the individual items. Consider creating an enumerated list of poems as in the following example, which also uses the `cleveref` package and its ability to assign optional parameters to `\label` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{poem}{poem}{poems}

\begin{document}
\section*{Nursery Rhymes}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Mary Had a Little Lamb \label[poem]{poem:mary}
   \begin{verse}
   Mary had a little lamb\\
   Its fleece was white as snow\\
   And everywhere that Mary went\\
   The lamb was sure to go.
   \end{verse}
\item Humpty Dumpty \label[poem]{poem:humpty}
   \begin{verse}
   Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall\\
   Humpty Dumpty had a great fall\\
   And all the king's horses and all the king's men\\
   Couldn't put Humpty together again.
   \end{verse}
\end{enumerate}

\Cref{poem:mary,poem:humpty} are among the best known nursery rhymes.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that a list doesn't display its "number" in-text by default even if one adds a (referable) counter to lists. Consider to put your list inside a `figure` environment and to provide a name for this figure with `\caption` -- this way, you may refer to the figure.

Note: `\eqref{listref}` produces nothing in your MWE because there's nothing to refer to in your document. Add `\section{foo}` immediately after `\begin{document}`, and your `\eqref` will (wrongly) refer to section 1.