# Make a tagged cross-reference to a group of items in an enumerate environment

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, tag

I have an enumerate environnement which enumerates a group of conditions :

```
    \begin{enumerate}
    \label{Conditions}
       \item Condition 1
       \item Condition 2
       \item Condition 3
    \end{enumerate}

Consider an object which satisfies the conditions~\eqref{Conditions}.
```

And I want to make a unique reference to the whole list of conditions, like if it was just an equation environment (with a number like (1.4) put at right of the 3 conditions).

I mean that I hope to have the same kind of display as if I just do

```
\begin{equation}
 a^2 = b^2 + c^2 /label{eq_1}
\end{equation}

Consider the equation~\eqref{eq_1}.
```

but for all this list of conditions instead of only one equation.

Comment: How about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32781/cross-reference-entire-enumerate-list